# How to prevent Image from scaling if its actual size is less than ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageView whose dimensions are 100 * 100.  I had an image who dimensions are 50 * 50 and this image needs to fit in ImageView. The Image scales to dimensions of ImageView. But I need the Image to remain its size which is 50 * 50 rather than scaling . Can any one help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I guess you are setting the image as background. Use src.

Comment: I am using setImageBitmap() method

Comment: Please provide some code on how you are doing it. Otherwise we can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If You set this in Your layout xml, use parameter:

```
        scaleType="center"
```

programmatically:

```
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
```

like described in the API:

ImageView.ScaleType:  CENTER = Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageview_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
imageview_logo.setAdjustViewBounds(true);        
imageview_logo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
```

I hope it will be helpful !